# How do i update servers to 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to login on cosmicpvp but it says this server is out of date as do all my other servers. Shouldn't they automatically update. Please help.

Comment: Do you manage the server?

Comment: It's up to the server owner to update the server, which could take them a long time if they have a lot of plugins to update. You may need to wait, or downgrade your client back to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spigot and you've downloaded **BuildTools.jar**, then you'll need to run it inside a folder. This folder will contain the *spigot.jar* file.

1. First, you need to download the **[minecraft server](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.9/minecraft_server.1.9.jar)** from
   Minecraft's official website. Skip this for spigot.
2. Then, replace your old minecraft_server.jar with this new one. With spigot, use the **spigot.jar** instead
3. Restart your server, and you're good to go!

EDIT: This will only work if you have access to edit the server's file.
Most servers will not support 1.9 because it's not available for Spigot, as said above.

**EDIT2: Spigot 1.9 is out! Download spigot [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/).**

To answer your question about automatically updating, this is not a thing. People will need to follow the step above to update their server for Spigot or Vanilla.
Also, this will be relatively fast, because the only thing that'll break plugins for 1.9 is sounds. A plugin that doesn't use sounds almost definitely works seamlessly on both 1.8 and 1.9